# Julia: Plot matrix with Gadfly.jl

Tags: julia, gadfly

I'm trying to plot a matrix with Gadfly, like I can do with PyPlot's `matshow`:

```
using PyPlot

p = eye(5)
p[5,5] = -1

matshow(p)
```

[image]

But I took a look at the docs, and found nothing. How can I do it with Gadfly?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Gadfly has a `spy()` function which does the same thing.

```
using Gadfly
p = eye(5)
p[end, end] = -1
spy(p)
```

You can check out the [source](https://github.com/dcjones/Gadfly.jl/blob/master/src/poetry.jl#L120) for more information.

Comment: How to have grayscale plot?