# Plotting nxn matrix as a headmap in Gadfly

Tags: julia, gadfly

Hi I am wondering how to plot a heatmap with Gadfly for a n x n matrix. From what I saw the closest thing is `Geom.rect` or `Geom.rectbin`, but I am unable to get it in the format of grid.

```
using Gadfly: Geom, plot
a = rand(3,3)
plot(x = 1:9, y=1:9,color = a, Geom.rectbin)
```

[image]

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24598690/julia-plot-matrix-with-gadfly-jl

Comment: [The example in the Gadfly docs](http://gadflyjl.org/stable/gallery/geometries/#[Geom.rect](@ref),-[Geom.rectbin](@ref)) might be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to use `spy()`:

```
using Gadfly
a=rand(9,9);
spy(a)
```

[image]

Comment: How would you add a text label inside each rectangle with the value of the element?